# In typescript, why is this not getting auto completed in vscode typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I am wondering why I am getting auto completions on the typescript playground correctly, but in vscode I am not getting auto completions. **I am getting auto completion everywhere else in vscode except in this case only.**
edit: I am also on ubuntu so maybe it's a probably with vscode for ubuntu?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAkIIBrOAbwCg5a4BBAE0YC44AKACxNIBUBPMMDYBnGFGQBzADRwArkgQBHOcHys4YiUhlxsmADYGARjlJsAYguwwEEJAEo4AXgB8cAG4QEjANw06AGFDAzYuHgEhUXEpWQA6BMwoSRE2TCR%20AG0AXSc3T28-ANoAJWAAWwgPYQ5uMkiarVj5RRU1DSadPPcvH386OAB9OtJUymKBuEzSYH5o7UlstmpJ1amZuc0YnSW4KyQbOyQJgYBfCdP-c4GqUEhYRBQ0LFw4XmAxegAFfHGBkbYRB4-ToyAQMHYDjYvSK5yo2HsYjgAIIxDILj%20dCYGnC9UEjW2ugUylU6nmzX0RlM2HMe2stns3Uop2kE2CRjCIwa5J08USyTG6SyuRc7goLImZUq1U5EXxPKJrVJHUJTPFrIGwx4Y3FVDhCKQSNQnx%20bHeJt%20zkxtBRI1ZEzBEIcKzWME4CBEcRGcQueqAA)

[image: Playground typescript]

[image]

I also disabled all my VSCode extensions and then restarted VSCode
[image]

Comment: obligatory: did you reload vscode?

Comment: I did not in the photo, but I just did and retried, still no proper auto complete. @TobiasS.

Comment: Is this inside of a `class`? Why is it `this.hook.` and not `hook.`?

Comment: @MikeS. it's of type `TestAPI` which has a property `hook` of type `IHook`. The code `this.hook` is correct.

Comment: the code I posted is a way to reproduce the results, so no it is not inside of a class. doing `hook.` does auto complete, but I would just like to use/understand `this.hook` @MikeS.

Comment: Oh I see now! My bad :)

Comment: vscode seems to be giving the correct autocompletion options for me, even in a newly created file that I pasted your code in... Do you by any chance have extensions that fiddle with Intellisense?

Comment: I just clicked the button that disabled all my VSCode extensions and the restarted vscode, and still no auto complete. I also added a new picture of the disabled extensions result (which looks like the 2nd picture :P)